# Facebook Integration for iOS4

Tags: facebook, ios4

i want to add the ability to post to the facebook wall trough my iPhone app. 
I found various possibilities to do that, but which one is the best and shortest for iOS4?

And do I need UIWebView?

Thanks mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use the [official facebook-ios-sdk](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). It does a good job of managing the OAuth authentication and other stuff for you, there is little for you to worry about. For example, it comes with the necessary authentication view and you don't need to store *any* credentials in your app thanks to cookies (and fact, since OAuth FB says you shouldn't store the credentials due to privacy). Plus, it's OSS and if you have trouble, you can ask for help in the [Facebook developer forum for SDKs](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewforum.php?id=55).

Comment: Thank you! I am going to test this solution today. Mat