# Implementing FBSessionDelegate protocol in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, facebook

I am trying to implement Facebook connect with an app I am create for iOS devices. I've followed all the directions to they key, and the SDK works, I get one warning though. It says I do not implement the FBSessionDelegate protocol. During the debugging in simulator it takes me into safari to signin to FB instead of doing it in the app itself. Is the FBSessionDelegate responsible for this? If so, how do I get it so it does it all within the app.

Answer (score 3):

Have you implemented methods from the `FBSessionDelegate` protocol as defined in `Facebook.h`?

```
@protocol FBSessionDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)fbDidLogin;
- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled;
- (void)fbDidLogout;
@end
```

These should be implemented in the object that is assigned to `delegate` in

```
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:<delegate object>];
```

It's probably a good idea to resolve that delegate warning first.

Comment: That may be my problem, I've been googling around and many of the sites I find only show the old way to implement FBConnect, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The latest FBConnect sdk does the job of managing the OAuth by itself. It is normal that the the signing-in takes you to the Facebook Connect page on safari. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730332/facebook-integration-for-ios4) thread

Comment: thanks mate, most help I've found uses the old method of FBConnect and it gets confusing figuring out which way is the right way with the current sdk

Comment: why don't u get help from the sample application present inside the sdk. It pretty much covers most of the basic things.

Answer (score 0):

The FBSessionDelegate is not responsible for this issue. The iOS SDK has a fallback to Safari if it can't launch the FB App.
In Facebook.m in this method:

```
- (void)authorizeWithFBAppAuth:(BOOL)tryFBAppAuth
                    safariAuth:(BOOL)trySafariAuth
```

...there is this comment:

```
  // If the device is running a version of iOS that supports multitasking,
  // try to obtain the access token from the Facebook app installed
  // on the device.
  // If the Facebook app isn't installed or it doesn't support
  // the fbauth:// URL scheme, fall back on Safari for obtaining the access token.
  // This minimizes the chance that the user will have to enter his or
  // her credentials in order to authorize the application.
```

This comment explains the reasons why Safari would be used instead of the FB App.

1. Is your simulator a device that
   supports multitasking?
2. Does your simulator have the FB App
   installed?
3. Is the FB App the latest version?
   (to make sure it supports the
   fbauth:// scheme)

The FBSessionDelegate, as dfrdmn explained, implements 3 methods that would all be called after the redirection to FB or Safari has already occurred and therefore isn't contributing to your issue.

To get rid of that warning there are a few things you need to make sure you do.

-- In your .h file make sure you implement the FBSessionDelegate.

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <FBSessionDelegate>
```

-- In your .h file make sure you #import "Facebook.h". Using @class Facebook will not work.

Comment: Thank your for your response. As you've said the latest Facebook SDK does try to use the FB app or then Safari for authentication. I wasn't testing it on the device so it was always falling back to Safari for authentication. Testing it on the device it does fall back to FB app for authentication. Thanks for all your support guys.